# WSClient - View debug/header information for web service calls in grails

Tags: web-services, debugging, grails, groovy

I currently am using WSClient with Groovy & Grails to connect to a web service.  I'm encountering however some pretty significant delays from when I hit the service, to when I actually receive data back.  It's a theory of mine that it's getting caught up in our proxy server, and that is causing the delay.

I'm looking for a way to see an output of what WSClient is actually doing... just to the console would be find, but am having trouble locating anything through Google and the reference books I have at my disposal.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these to your Config.groovy should help:

```
log4j = {
   debug 'grails.app',
         'groovyx.net.ws',
         'org.apache.cxf'
}
```

The only other thing I would suggest is to do a bit of [profiling and tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719711/performance-tuning-profiling-of-grails-apps) to attempt to track down the source of the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) useful. Despite the name, this can be used for debugging either SOAP or REST services, and is available as a standalone app or IDE plugin.

Comment: I have used soapUI for other troubleshooting activities, but I specifically need to see how Grails is actually connecting to determine if there is an issue.